# Fifo Inventory with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, fifo

I need one adaptation for the first table because there are negative issues points and I need the net table considerating the negatives points as debit of the first time of issue. E.g:

```
FechaEmi Cuenta PtosEmi PtosCan
30/06/2015  1   100     0
31/07/2015  1   120     0
31/08/2015  1   130     0
31/08/2015  1   0       55
30/09/2015  1   50      0
31/10/2015  1   30      0
30/11/2015  1   70      0
31/12/2015  1   95      0
31/01/2016  1   50      0
29/02/2016  1   0       74
31/03/2016  1   50      0
30/04/2016  1   15      0
30/06/2015  2   20      0
31/07/2015  2   30      0
31/08/2015  2   40      0
30/09/2015  2   350     0
30/06/2015  3   150     0
31/07/2015  3   120     0
31/08/2015  3   0       56
31/08/2015  3   220     0
30/06/2015  4   70      0
31/07/2015  4   134     0
31/08/2015  4   12      0
30/06/2015  5   97      0
31/07/2015  5   130     0
31/08/2015  5   15      0
30/09/2015  5   135     0
31/10/2015  5   20      0
30/11/2015  5   140     0
31/12/2015  5   25      0
31/01/2016  5   145     0
29/02/2016  5   0       25
```

where:

FechaEmi= Date;

Cuenta=ID;

PtosEmi=Issues points;

PtosCan=Canceled points

I want this table

```
FechaEmi    Cuenta  PtosEmi
30/06/2015  1   0
31/07/2015  1   91
31/08/2015  1   130
30/09/2015  1   50
31/10/2015  1   30
30/11/2015  1   70
31/12/2015  1   95
31/01/2016  1   50
31/03/2016  1   50
30/04/2016  1   15
30/06/2015  2   20
31/07/2015  2   30
31/08/2015  2   40
30/09/2015  2   350
30/06/2015  3   94
31/07/2015  3   120
31/08/2015  3   220
30/06/2015  4   70
31/07/2015  4   134
31/08/2015  4   12
30/06/2015  5   72
31/07/2015  5   130
31/08/2015  5   15
30/09/2015  5   135
31/10/2015  5   20
30/11/2015  5   140
31/12/2015  5   25
31/01/2016  5   145
```

I have this code. The problem is that doesn't do anything with the points that were debited in a date that there are not issues point. How can you recommend me change that query? Thanks!

```
with cte as( 
select Fechaemi, Cuenta,PtosEmi,PtosCan
,row_number() over (partition by Fechaemi,Cuenta order by Fechaemi,Cuenta) as rank 
from emision) 
select a.Fechaemi, a.Cuenta,a.PtosEmi - coalesce(b.PtosCan, 0) stock 
from cte a 
left join cte b on 
a.FechaEmi= b.FechaEmi and a.Cuenta = b.Cuenta and a.rank = b.rank - 1 
where a.PtosEmi - coalesce(b.PtosCan, 0) > 0 order by a.cuenta asc, a.fechaemi asc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/556c7/3)

```
with totalPay as( 
    SELECT Cuenta, SUM(PtosCan) TotalPayment
    FROM emision
    GROUP BY Cuenta
),
totalDebt as (
    SELECT FechaEmi, Cuenta, (SELECT SUM(PtosEmi) 
                              FROM emision e2 
                              WHERE e2.FechaEmi <= e.FechaEmi
                              AND   e2.Cuenta = e.Cuenta                          
                             ) AS TotalDebt
    FROM emision e
    WHERE   e.PtosEmi <> 0
)
select  
    e.FechaEmi, 
    e.Cuenta, 
    e.PtosEmi, 
    td.TotalDebt, 
    tp.TotalPayment,
    CASE 
        WHEN td.TotalDebt < tp.TotalPayment THEN 0
        WHEN td.TotalDebt - tp.TotalPayment > PtosEmi THEN PtosEmi
        ELSE td.TotalDebt - tp.TotalPayment
    END Remaining
FROM 
    totalDebt  td inner join 
    totalPay tp on td.Cuenta = tp.Cuenta inner join
    emision e on td.FechaEmi = e.FechaEmi AND td.Cuenta = e.Cuenta
WHERE 
    e.PtosEmi <> 0
```

Comment: Juan Carlos, thanks for your answer, but I need that the 50 points canceled in June be debit of the first issue, like FIFO. So I need to be debit of the 30-April. Do you know how can I make it?

Comment: Can you expand a litle more the sample? like include more cancel... I dont understand how the cancel are apply yet. I imagine if i pay 425 for cuenta 1 in june the result will be (april, 0) (may, 0) (june, 25) ?

Comment: Yes, sorry! I have changed the original question and I add a longer table!

Comment: Is better if you put your sample in a sqlfiddle demo like the one I show here

Comment: Please check now my new edit. Result is the remainning column, but I include the other columns so you see the calculations

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! This is exactly what I want! :)

Answer (score 1):

Possibly not the most elegant, but explicit way:

```
WITH 
PtosEmi AS(
  SELECT FechaEmi, cuenta, SUM(PtosEmi) as PtosEmi
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY FechaEmi, cuenta),
PtosCan AS (
  SELECT MIN(FechaEmi) as FechaEmi, cuenta, SUM(PtosCan) as PtosCan 
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY cuenta)
SELECT 
  e.FechaEmi, 
  e.cuenta, 
  e.ptosemi, 
  c.ptoscan,
  e.ptosemi - COALESCE(c.ptoscan, 0) total
FROM 
  PtosEmi e LEFT JOIN 
  PtosCan c ON e.FechaEmi = c.FechaEmi AND e.cuenta = c.cuenta
ORDER BY e.cuenta, e.FechaEmi
```

This is based on the assumption that you cannot have cancellations before anything was issued for give cuenta.

Also if you have more cancelled items in total compared to what was issued initially, total value will be negative.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9ac40/11

**Update**

as you want to reduce cancellations line by line here is updated query:

```
WITH 
ptosemi AS(
    SELECT FechaEmi, cuenta, 
           PtosEmi as PtosEmi,
           SUM(PtosEmi) OVER (PARTITION BY cuenta ORDER BY FechaEmi) runsum 
    FROM table1),
PtosCan AS (
    SELECT cuenta, SUM(PtosCan) as PtosCan 
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY cuenta)
SELECT 
  e.FechaEmi, 
  e.cuenta, 
  e.ptosemi, 
  e.runsum,
  c.ptoscan,
  CASE 
    WHEN e.runsum <= c.ptoscan
    THEN 0 
    WHEN c.ptoscan BETWEEN e.runsum - e.ptosemi AND e.runsum
    THEN e.runsum - COALESCE(c.ptoscan, 0)
    ELSE e.ptosemi END total
FROM 
 ptosemi e LEFT JOIN 
 PtosCan c ON e.cuenta = c.cuenta
ORDER BY e.cuenta, e.FechaEmi
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8036c2/25

Comment: I think the payment should go in all the rows not just the first one as show now in the larger sample. [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8036c2/1)

Comment: Yes, this solution will not work for the updated set.

Comment: updated the answer, interestingly very similar to yours. I guess that is the way to go then )

Comment: You can test with my fiddle, I update with the new data sample.

Comment: Any particular reason you do `SUM over partition` instead of `GROUP BY` ??

Comment: I don't think you can do GROUP by in OVER()