# SQL - Knocking off Accordingly

Tags: sql, sql-server, fifo

I have an issue in SQL where all transaction just come into one giant messy tables.

Example:

```
1 | Invoice | $300
2 | Invoice | $250
3 | Payment | $100
4 | Invoice | $200
5 | Payment | $300
```

So i will have `3 invoices` and `2 payments`but

the `Payment` at `line 3` can only be knocking off the `Invoice` on `line 1`
and `Payment` on `line 5` is for the `Invoice` in `line 2`.

I want to `Net Off` the `Payment` and Find rather it is an `Overpayment` or `Underpayment` or it is knocking off entire invoice.

How can i do this?

Comment: What have to tried so far

Comment: honestly, i dont know anywhere to starts

Comment: Fix your database structure, There is no way to 100% be sure that the received payment is for the previous Invoice.

Comment: sorry thomas - Fixing the DB is out of the question - we didnt own the DB - we just need to do analysis on the "available" data

Comment: As @thomasvdberge says, failing a reference to the original invoice ID on the payment, there's no way you can know for sure which payment settles which invoice. You can get the overall balance like so: `select sum( amount * if type='invoice' then 1 else -1 endif ) from lousyTable`

Comment: what dbms is this for? is there **any other data**? is there more than one table? (you have use "table**s**")

Comment: @Sagar 

Ive been thinking if i can put a TEMP Flag on the Invoice and The Payment according to occurrence , then i can do the ( Payment 1) - (Invoice 1)

Comment: @user3128417 its also an option..

Comment: @Used_By_Already - its a MSSQL. not other data is available and this is just from 1 single table.

Comment: @Sagar - if i were to do that ? How can i put a Flag on each transaction accordingly ?

Comment: @VincentBuck - what if i can put a TEMP Flag on the Invoice and The Payment according to occurrence , then i can do the ( Payment 1) - (Invoice 1)

How do i flag them accordingly ?

Comment: can you add expected result to you question pls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fifo Inventory with SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657980/fifo-inventory-with-sql)

Comment: @Bulat please don't invent pointless tags

Answer (score 0):

This is easy using `ROW_NUMBER()`. Assume there must be an invoice before payment.

```
SELECT 
    i.Id AS InvoiceId, p.Id AS PaymentId,
    CASE 
        WHEN RefAmount = 0 THEN 'Settled' 
        WHEN RefAmount > 0 THEN 'Underpayment' 
        ELSE 'Overpayment' 
    END AS State
FROM
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS GroupId, * 
        FROM messy WHERE Type = 'Invoice'
    ) i
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS GroupId, * 
        FROM messy WHERE Type = 'Payment'
    ) p ON i.GroupId = p.GroupId
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT i.Amount - ISNULL(p.Amount, 0) AS RefAmount) r
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f4a70/2)